# delete last elements from QML Model ( QAbstractListModel from C++)

Tags: qt, qml

I have QML models from C++ (QAbstractListModel) and I use Listviews anfd Gridviews to show it (for example, with my model  "DM_valves")

I have one model with 16 elements, but I only want to show less elements (for example, at startup I can ve a variable like "number_on_elements=5)

I think that is not possible to limit the maximun number of elements in a ListView, so I want to try to delete elements to my QAbstractListModel in the QML side.

is possible?how?

Comment: One approach would be to add a filter proxy whose `number_of_elements` property is exposed to QML.

Comment: Have you tried to use `DelegateModel` [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-delegatemodel.html)? You can create a group named `firstGroup`, and the condition to be in that group would be `index < 5` and your view displays this group.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something as simple as this:

```
ListView {
  id: view
  model: mod
  height: 50
  width: 50
  property int maxCount: 5
  delegate: Rectangle {
    height: visible ? 20 : 0
    width: visible ? 20 : 0
    visible: index < view.maxCount
    Text {
      anchors.centerIn: parent
      text: index
    }
  }
}
```

The trick is to make the size of the invisible elements zero so they don't take any space in the view.

It will not be efficient if you have thousands of model items and complex delegates, since all the delegates will be created in memory, even if not visible. You could use a loader and only load the actual item for visible list items.

Also consider limiting the count in your `QAbstractListModel` implementation, you could have a maxCount variable, and in

`rowCount() { return maxCount ? std::min(maxCount, yourList.size()) : yourList.size(); }`

this way if maxCount is not zero, the model can report less than its actual size.

Comment: great!!! a very simple solution. Delegate model seems good too. I use proxymodels in C++, but I need a QML side solutions